# Spring MVC controller with multiple @RequestBody

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I was wondering if for example a SpringMVC controller can have a method signature such as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/target", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public void acceptObject(@RequestBody MyObjectDto dto,@RequestBody String messageBody) {
    //Authenticate messageBody
    //Process mapped DTO
}
```

The intention was that JSON would be posted to this controller, the raw message body would be authenticated for integrity, and if correct, the JSON would be mapped to a DTO that could be handed off for processing.

At the moment I end up with

```
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

Comment: Have you managed to solve this problem yet? I am encountering the same issue and am thinking about opening another thread on it, since the answer below is not really what I am looking for.

Comment: The answer can be summed up as 'No' so the general solution is to simply  accept the message body as a string, verify it's integrity and then manually map this string to an object using Jackson.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring uses an interface called `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` to decide which arguments it will pass to your handler methods. For parameters annotated with `@RequestBody` it uses a class called [`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.html). This class basically looks in a set of `HttpMessageConverter` objects for one that can read the `content-type` of the request and can convert to the specified type. If it finds one, it passes the body of the `HttpServletRequest` as an `InputStream` to the `HttpMessageConverter` object.

In this case, you will probably find some JSON deserializer doing work. It very likely (seeing the `IOException` you get) consuming the stream and then closing it.

So really this way to do things isn't directly possible.

One solution is to make a `Filter` that wraps the `HttpServletRequest` in your own implementation that buffers the `InputStream` to make it reusable/re-readable as many times as are required. But again the rules for deserializing from the body might be assumed by Spring and not be what you want exactly. In this case you can create your own `Annotation` and `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` which you then register with the application in your configuration. You can then control exactly how things are deserialized from the request body.

Another solution is to combine both `MyObjectDto` and `messageBody` into one DTO, if that makes sense to your data model (and to the Spring deserialization process).