# Passing a DTO and other values in @RequestBody in Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

I want a pass a dto and another value using the @RequestBody in spring. Something like shown in below,(This is my controller code)

```
public User createUser( @RequestBody @Validated UserDto userDto,@RequestBody Integer roleId ){
        return userService.createUser(userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getEmail(), userDto.getPassword(),roleId);
    }
```

Below is the json I'm sending via the post call.

```
{
  "username": "usernameABC",
  "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "emailRepeat" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "password" : "asdasd",
  "passwordRepeat" : "asdasd",
  "roleId" : 1
}
```

Is it possible to do this? or do I have to include the **roleId** in the dto itself?

Comment: Yes it is possible, do you get an error or what?

Comment: @STaefi i get a 400 error

Comment: use `@RequestParam` for passing `roleId` you can't pass  mutiple `@RequestBody` in one request

Answer (score 1):

You must include roleId in DTO. @RequestBody bind json into one Object.
[see this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12893566/passing-multiple-variables-in-requestbody-to-a-spring-mvc-controller-using-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

You should create a POJO that has the properties that match your JSON and then everything is easier, because spring knows how to convert the data. You don't need any @RequestBody stuff in your DB layer. Keep that stuff in the controller. Your DB layer should just accept POJOs to persist, and not even know if it's coming from a request or not. Could be test case for example.

Here's how i do it:

```
@RequestMapping(value = API_PATH + "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@OakSession
public @ResponseBody SignupResponse signup(@RequestBody SignupRequest req) {
    logRequest("signup", req);
    SignupResponse res = new SignupResponse();
    userManagerService.signup(req, res, false);
    return res;
}
```

Taken from here: (My project)

https://github.com/Clay-Ferguson/meta64/blob/master/src/main/java/com/meta64/mobile/AppController.java

Comment: this is my controller. Not the db layer.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public User createUser( @RequestBody @Validated UserDto userDto,@RequestParam Integer roleId ){
    return userService.createUser(userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getEmail(), userDto.getPassword(),roleId);
}
```

for passing value from url use
`localhost:8085/user/user-api?roleId =45632`
with json

```
{
  "username": "usernameABC",
  "email" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "emailRepeat" : "abc@gmail.com",
  "password" : "asdasd",
  "passwordRepeat" : "asdasd",
}
```

OR

you can also add roleId into your UserDto class

Comment: I knew this could be possible. I want to know if can pass all on the request body.

Comment: yes you can ..then just create your `UserDto` with `roleId` property and other and pass as  `@RequestBody`

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27189730/multiple-requestbody-values-in-one-controller-method ...You cannot use two @RequestBody as it can bind to a single object only (the body can be consumed only once).